# Can a kubernetes cluster share windows and linux nodes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers

I am trying to create windows nodes in an already existing kubernetes cluster in Azure. The kubernetes cluster has two Linux nodes running on them.

I am trying to use az aks cli to create windows nodes but I don't see any option.

So can we create Linux and Windows nodes in the same kubernetes cluster? If yes, How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is posible, but not using the CLI\portal (at this stage). You need to use [ACS engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine).

You need to use this definition (adjust it to your needs):
https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/examples/windows/kubernetes-hybrid.json

There is a bit of a learning curve, but not that hard.
https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/deploy.md
https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/clusterdefinition.md

Comment: Thank you so much. I went through the links, and if I understood it correctly we have to create a cluster in acs for hybrid nodes and it is currently not possible to add nodes to already existing cluster created using aks?

Comment: aks != acs. you can add nodes to aks (scale), but multiple pools and hybrid pools are not yet supported

Comment: Hello @4c74356b41, one more question. Can Azure AKS use arm templates to spin up nodes? We have ARM templates that we use to currently spin our VM's and wish to extend the same templates using AKS.

Comment: yeah, but its not exactly straight forward, here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters